# Можно ли заменить точки с запятыми на запятые без потери смысла и нужен ли знак перед «и Серебряную пагоду»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, стилистика, точка-с-запятой

Помпезно-вычурный комплекс до сих пор является действующей королевской резиденцией, поэтому туристам показывают лишь часть залов: Тронный, где проходили церемонии коронации монархов; павильон Чан Чая, в котором проводились танцевальные представления; и Серебряную пагоду, пол которой выложен плитами из серебра.

Answer (score 5):

Можно, точка с запятой - знак факультативный, но он вносит стройность и ясность,отделяя части однородных членов с распространяющими их придаточными предложениями.

Перед И запятая, закрывающая придаточное, обязательна, но если там будет точка с запятой, тоже будет верно (если везде останутся точки с запятой).